Anchor IDL failing to initialize in TS SDK with `Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.split')`
I'm loading legacy IDLs in the Solana Explorer (explorer.solana.com) and but some old IDLs just don't pass the toCamelCase check here: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/ts/packages/anchor/src/program/index.ts#L290
I'm upcasting the legacy IDLs to the current spec via https://github.com/solana-labs/explorer/blob/7a1ba29a46cf8538cea152d15fc236e681ef889a/app/utils/convertLegacyIdl.ts#L439
Wondering if anyone else has seen & solved this issue?

Turns out this was just an issue with how I ported anchor idl convert to TS.
Fix here: https://github.com/solana-labs/explorer/pull/399
